# How to pass values from webgrid using javascript to another action page?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I Have a Webgrid in MVC3, it has an edit column. On clicking the column the the ID of the row has to be passed to another *action page* where I have written the edit action. How can I run a Javascript function on clicking the edit column in the Webgrid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this for your edit link in your view:

```
Html.ActionLink(article.Title, 
                "Item",   // <-- ActionMethod
                "Login",  // <-- Controller Name.
                new { ItemID = Model.ItemID }, // <-- Route arguments.
                null  // <-- htmlArguments .. which are none. You need this value
                      //     otherwise you call the WRONG method ...
                )
```